# Angularjs select boxes updating progress

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few select boxes when I click an item in a box I want to update a progress bar ... Each selection of the boxes should be added to progress... when I change the value of a specific box the former value should be "subtracted" and the new one should be added. So that 100% shouldn't be overflown.

Example: in the first box I choose an item with 90% progress in the second box I choose an item with 10 % progress in my solution when I now change the item in the first select box the progress value gets added to the 100%.
Didn't found any idea or solution to work around

```
...
    <select
        id="inputFarbe"
        class="form-control nullable"
        ng-model="signup.carConfiguration.farbe"
        ng-change="updateProgress(signup.carConfiguration.farbe)"
        ng-options="item.name for item in items | itemFilter:3">
            <option value="">-- hier auswählen --</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progress}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{progress}}%;">
        {{progress}}%
    </div>
    $scope.updateProgress = function(itemProg){ 
        $scope.progress += parseInt(progressCount[itemProg]);
    }
...
```

[Selectboxes for Progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0UYg.jpg)

My progress bar has 50% cause of Serie BMW 1er i choose Model 3Türer now my progress bar has 60% if i change to Model: 5 türer the 10 percent should be subtracted and 5 % added so it has 55% now.... with the other select boxes it should be the same

Comment: So in your case, if you have 2 select boxes, the values from both the boxes should always add upto 100%. Anything more should be rejected. Is that your case ?

Comment: they should add up but can be at 60 percent or 80 percent or anything else ... but if i change the value of one select box the old value of the select box should be subtracted and the new should be added ... and i have more then two select boxes there are 6 select boxes

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$watch` as it gives you the old and the new value.

```
$scope.$watch('signup.carConfiguration.farbe', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.progress -= parseInt(progressCount[oldValue]);
    $scope.progress += parseInt(progressCount[newValue]);
});
```

Another solution would be to sum up all variables each change:

```
$scope.updateProgress = function() {
    $scope.progress = parseInt(progressCount[$scope.signup.carConfiguration.farbe]) + parseInt(progressCount[$scope.valueFromSecondSelectBox]);
};
```

BTW: I think it is better to use `ng-style` instead of just `style`.